# What are the reasons for server crash?

Tags: tomcat, web-applications, crash, webserver, tomcat7

I would like to know when a Tomcat server crash, I know that a full memory or an exception in a web application can lead to a crash, but what are the possible other reasons?

I am developing a web application and I am sure that my application does not over fill the memory. There is no exceptions the application as well (no exception found in my catalina.out file), my server just stops.

By the way, I have a "recover-tomcat.sh" shell file who check the status of Tomcat and restart it if necessary. It looks like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
SERVICE=/etc/init.d/tomcat7
STOPPED_MESSAGE=" * Tomcat servlet container is not running."
PID_FILE_MESSAGE=" * Tomcat servlet engine is not running, but pid file exists."

if [ "`$SERVICE status`" == "$STOPPED_MESSAGE" ];
then
{
     print "tomcat not running"  
     $SERVICE start
}
else
    if [ "`$SERVICE status`" == "$PID_FILE_MESSAGE" ];
    then
    {
        $SERVICE restart
    }
    fi
fi
```

Another related question is, what are the reasons for getting the message?

```
* Tomcat servlet engine is not running, but pid file exists.
```

The recover file is called every 5 minutes by cron, My crontab file is like follow:

```
SHELL=/bin/bash
# monitor tomcat every 5 minutes
*/5 * * * * sudo /bin/recover-tomcat.sh
```

Answer (score 1):

> a full memory [can lead to a crash]

Yes.

> or an exception in a web application [can lead to a crash]

No.

What *symptoms* are you experiencing?

Comment: Thank EJP for your comment, actually the server stops suddenly, how can I track the server activities to see when and why it stops or crashes? I am checking the catalina.out but I do not see any up-normal message. My application is running normally, I also checked the log of the application, and there is always a free memory available.

Comment: Actually, why and when this status happens: * Tomcat servlet engine is not running, but pid file exists. ?